# How to call procedure with IN and INOUT values in Postgres Procedure

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, procedure

I have migrated oracle databases to Aurora Postgresql on RDS AWS, With the help of AWS SCT(Schema Conversion Tool). Some of the Packages in Oracle converted to postgres in below format.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE miptd."pkg_rpt$strptst"(i_molo text,INOUT o_cursor refcursor)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
DECLARE

    o_cursor$ATTRIBUTES aws_oracle_data.TCursorAttributes;
    
BEGIN   
    o_cursor := NULL;
    OPEN o_cursor FOR
    
    EXECUTE CONCAT_WS('','select count(ID) From 
                        (select DISTINCT D.ID, B.CSS_DISTRICT, B.RDA, C.TECH_TYPE, C.FORECAST_DATE, D.SITE_TYPE
                        FROM
                        ALB.VIEWSIRPT B, 
                        ALB.VIEWWRDATA C,
                        ALB.', i_molo, ' D
                        WHERE
                        (D.CSR = C.CSR) AND (D.CUSTOMER = C.CUSTOMER)
                        AND (D.CSR = B.CSR ) AND (D.CUSTOMER = B.CUSTOMER )  )a ');

    o_cursor$ATTRIBUTES := ROW (TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL);
END;
$BODY$;
```

Not aware of cursors usage in postgres
How do I call the procedure. ?
Where do i see my result value by calling the procedure?
Is it ok to convert this as a function ?

Comment: A procedure does not return any value. If you need to catch the result of this logic, wrap it in a `function` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a function, and you should avoid SQL injection:

```
CREATE function some_name(i_molo text) RETURNS bigint
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   RETURN EXECUTE
      format('SELECT count(ID)
              FROM (SELECT DISTINCT D.ID,
                                    B.CSS_DISTRICT,
                                    B.RDA, C.TECH_TYPE,
                                    C.FORECAST_DATE,
                                    D.SITE_TYPE
                    FROM ALB.%I D
                       JOIN ALB.VIEWWRDATA C
                          ON D.CUSTOMER = C.CUSTOMER AND D.CSR = C.CSR
                       JOIN ALB.VIEWSIRPT B
                          ON D.CUSTOMER = B.CUSTOMER AND D.CSR = B.CSR
                   ) AS a',
              i_molo);
END;$$;
```

Comment: Thanks. the above code throwing a syntax error at format('SELECT count(ID) .

Comment: I forgot a comma.